# Add new branches in forked repo from another's forked repos

Tags: git, github

I have three forked repos and base repo, let it be

- base_repo
- forked_repo_1

  - branch_1
  - branch_2
- forked_repo_2

  - branch_1
  - branch_2
- forked_repo_3

  - branch_1
  - branch_2

Now I want to add `branch_2` from `forked_repo_2` as `branch_3` in `forked_repo_1`
and
`branch_2` from `forked_repo_3` as `branch_4` in `forked_repo_1`

After that I want to delete  `forked_repo_2` and  `forked_repo_3` and work only in  `forked_repo_1`.

I found answers, that I can:

```
git remote add new_origins {link_to_forked_repo_2}
```

but I'm scary that I lost `branch_3` and `branch_4` if I delete `forked_repo_2` and `forked_repo_3`

Can you advise me, please, on the best way to do this?

Comment: "Best" is almost always a matter of opinion. Adding extra remotes will *work*. Branch names are not important; what matter are the commits and their hash IDs. Using a remote, your `git fetch` will obtain the commits, and create or update *remote-tracking names* (Git calls these "remote-tracking branch names" but they are not *branch* names) to help you find the commits.

Comment: Note that your own repository's remote-tracking names simply remember branch names and the corresponding hash IDs as found in some other repository. If you want to remember the commit hash IDs without the remote-tracking names, you can create your own names (branch names, tag names, or any other kind of name you care to invent) to remember the hash IDs.